# Find the image of the semi-infinite strip $x≥0$, $0≤y≤π$ under the transformation $w= \exp(z)$, and label corresponding portions of the boundary

Tags: complex-analysis

I am reading complex variables and applications book and I encountered this problem in the excercises:
"Find the image of the semi-infinite strip $x≥0$, $0≤y≤π$ under the transformation $w=\exp(z)$, and label corresponding portions of the boundary"

My attempt: let $x+iy$ be a point in the z plane. We have $w=e^x \cos y + ie^x \sin y = u+iv$
When $x \in [0,\infty)$, $e^x \in [1,\infty)$, and $\cos y\in [-1,1]$ when $y \in [0,\pi]$
So $u \in (-\infty,\infty)$
And since $\sin y \in [0,1]$ then $v \in [0,\infty)$
So $u+iv$ is definitely in the upper half of the w plane.
Now I don't know how to continue from here.
Any hint is much appreciated

Edit: calculating $u^2+v^2$ gives us $e^{2x}$ which we have its interval, I'm not sure if this can help or not.

Comment: It might be helpful to think about the modulus and argument of the image.

Comment: @saulspatz can you please check my edit and see if my thoughts are helpful or not?

Answer (score 1):

We have $$w=e^z=e^{x+iy}=e^xe^{iy}$$  Therefore, $$|w|=e^x\geq1,\\0\leq\arg w\leq\pi$$ so that $w$ lies in the portion of the closed upper half plane external to the open unit disk.  Furthermore the map is onto, because if $w=re^{i\theta}$ with $r\geq1$ and $0\leq\theta\leq\pi$ then $e^{x+iy}=w$, where $x=\log r\geq0,$ and $y=\theta$.

Comment: @mjw.  Thanks.  I'll fix it.

Comment: Sure, you're welcome.